# SQL - Can not SELECT data from a specific table

Tags: sql

```
$rs77 = $connector->query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE topic='1' AND date='$date' ORDER BY cpc DESC LIMIT 4");

    while ($rw77 = $connector->fetchArray($rs77))
    {
        switch($rw77['type']) {
            case "vid":
            ?>.... This is just a little part of my code.
```

It worked ok, and in one moment (didn't any kind of changes in db or in code).I tried to display mysql_error. But it doesnt show me nothing.

```
 $your_query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE topic='1' AND date='$date' ORDER BY cpc DESC LIMIT 4";
     $value = mysql_query($your_query) or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: " . $your_query . "<br /> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
```

What can be the problem? Thank you.

UPDATE: all other tables work nice. I can select data from them.

Here is my table:
[image]

Comment: what is $date? is it being replaced by a variable somewhere not shown?

Comment: it's a variable which contains current date:
$date = date("d.m.Y");

Comment: if you remove the date condition, does it work?

Comment: it works but i need this condition. i tried to set another variable with the same value as $date, but it doesn't work as well

date variable was in a file wich includes this file, i seted another variable in this files, right before my query starts, with a different name, and it doesn't work. what i'm amazed about is that it worked really nice, and i one moment i doesn't.

Comment: @atilla thank you for your ateention. my fault. so simple. 
it selectes records only from today's date, and i don't have any in my table. pulled my hair out until found it out. thank you for your tip.